# Magento2 : I want to get the Bundle Product Id from Bundle product detail page

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I created a bundle product and when I try to get that Bundle product id on product detail page I am getting simple product id of that bundle product instead of Bundle product id.
I used this function to get bundle id but its giving all the parent bundle products id instead of current bundle product id :

```
    $model = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');
    $product = $this->product;
    $parentIds = $model->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

in your block

```
protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
```

in your template

```
  $currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();   $id = $currentProduct->getId();
```

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: please accept the answer to helps others.

Comment: but its not working in API